# Jest encountered an unexpected token: SyntaxError: Unexpected Token {

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

## Issue:

I am running my tests with Jest and Enzyme when I came across this error when I was running my code on a different machine.

When I run `npm test` which only runs `jest --coverage --verbose` it will get this error every time. However, this doesn't happen when I run it on my work lap top.

[image: Jest Error]

What I'm trying to figure out is why this is breaking over the "{" token when I run my testing script. I've seen some people suggest that using babel-jest would help, but I don't believe that is the cause of this issue, as it doesn't affect my work laptop. I've also read that babel-jest doesn't resolve this issue.

Any assitance would be greatly appreciated.

---

## Here is the setUp file that it's referring to:

**setUptests.js**

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme'; // eslint-disable-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies

import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'; // eslint-disable-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

My **webpack.config.js**:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    base: path.resolve(__dirname, './app/app.jsx'),
    redux: path.resolve(__dirname, './app/reduxApp.jsx'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['env', 'react', 'stage-2'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
};
```

My **package.json** has the **configurations** for my jest here:

```
"jest": {
    "testURL": "http://localhost/",
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./setUpTests.js",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "node_modules/react/",
      "node_modules/enzyme/"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "statements": 98,
        "branches": 91,
        "functions": 98,
        "lines": 98
      }
    }
  }
```

and here are the list of **dependencies** that I'm using:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.4.1",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.2.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.10.0",
    "jest": "^23.4.2",
    "jsdom": "^11.12.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.2",
    "webpack": "^4.16.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
```

---

### UPDATE:

Attempted to switch the code from:
`import { configure } from 'enzyme';`
to:
`import Enzyme from 'enzyme';`

I'm assuming its an import issue at the moment. Will continue to research to see what will fix this.

[image: Removed destructuring and declared with Enzyme]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it is being answered in similar questions. The way I got around it was to install two class babel plugins:

```
npm install --save babel-plugin-transform-class-properties
npm install --save babel-plugin-syntax-class-properties
```

and include them in your **.babelrc** file:

```
"plugins": [
  "transform-class-properties",
  "syntax-class-properties"
 ]
```

After restarting the tests, the error should be gone :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Comment: I gave it a try, but I ended up getting an error on Enzyme. It's saying its an unexpected identifier. I'll update the post with the error screen, God willing.

Comment: I just updated the post. It's SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier, and it points to Enzyme on one machine, or import on the other

Comment: Still trying some different things. It's looking to be a babel set-up issue, but not sure why it works for some machines and not others

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following plugin to your `.babelrc` config file in order to fix the `import Enzyme` error:

`"plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]`