# Jest encountered an unexpected token SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, babeljs, enzyme

Hi I am using jest + enzyme for unit testing of reactjs application and having my company owned libraries in JavaScript(ES6) as node_modules, while transforming these node_modules, it is throwing below error 
[image]
[image]
It is throwing error at import "{"

I am using below as jest transformer: 
[image]

I am using as below jest config:
[image]

Below is my babel.config.js:
[image]
And below are my dependencies: 
  "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
 "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.1.0",
 "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
  "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
"jest": "^23.6.0",
"ts-jest": "23.10.5",

Please do let me know if I am missing anything or what babel plugin/preset is required to get rid of this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51867183/jest-encountered-an-unexpected-token-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: I tried @KenoClayton it was not resolving. thank you

Comment: I have resolved this by adding  "^.+\\.(js|jsx)?$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest", for transform, that has included jsx and babel-jest from node_modules folder not custom transformer. Thanks to the link given here https://medium.com/@samuelpouyt/how-to-solve-vue-error-with-jest-e8e9ff7d0cec

Comment: Ok, glad you managed to get it resolved!